# How to change WPF Combo-Box style hover effect

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've created a custom Combo Box style in WPF, but there is this irritating blue hover effect that I believe has to do with the `FocusVisualStyle` but i'm not sure.
I've tried editing the Background, Border, MouseOver Trigger and FocusVisualStyle but still nothing.
**Custom ComboBox Style**

```
<Style x:Key="CB" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#b3b3b3" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0 0 0 2"/>
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Regular" />
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="50"/>
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="32"/>
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                        <Grid>

                            <!--ToggleButton-->
                            <ToggleButton Name="ToggleButton" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                          FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}"
                                          Grid.Column="2"
                                          Focusable="false"
                                          IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                          ClickMode="Press">

                                <Border x:Name="templateRoot" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Background="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="Transparent">
                                    <Border x:Name="splitBorder" Width="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Margin="200 0 0 0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Transparent">
                                        <Path x:Name="arrow" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0 0 0 0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Fill="#333333" Data="M0,0 L0,2 L4,6 L8,2 L8,0 L4,4 z"/>
                                    </Border>
                                </Border>
                            </ToggleButton>

                            <ContentPresenter
                                Name="ContentSite"
                                IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                                ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                                Margin="0 0 0 5"
                                FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}"/>
                            <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
                                Style="{x:Null}"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                Margin="3,3,23,3"
                                Focusable="True"                               
                                Visibility="Hidden"
                                IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"/>
                            <Popup Name="Popup"
                                Placement="Bottom"
                                IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
                                AllowsTransparency="True"
                                Focusable="False"
                                PopupAnimation="Slide"
                                FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}">
                                <Grid Name="DropDown"
                                      SnapsToDevicePixels="True"               
                                      MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                                      MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}"
                                      FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}">
                                    <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder"
                                            Background="White"
                                            BorderThickness="1.5"
                                            BorderBrush="{x:Null}"
                                            FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}">
                                        <Border.Effect>
                                            <DropShadowEffect Opacity="0.6" ShadowDepth="3" BlurRadius="2"/>
                                        </Border.Effect>
                                    </Border>

                                    <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}">
                                        <StackPanel FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                                    </ScrollViewer>
                                </Grid>
                            </Popup>

                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                                <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="True"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="0 0 10 10"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="Margin" Value="0,-5,0,0"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Visibility"  Value="Visible"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="arrow" Property="Fill" Value="White" />
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The effect you are describing is the mouse over effect of the `ToggleButton`. You need to override the `ControlTemplate` of the `ToggleButton` in order to override its default behavior:

```
<!--ToggleButton-->
<ToggleButton Name="ToggleButton" >
  <ToggleButton.Style>
    <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
      <Setter Property="Background" 
              Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Background}"/>
      <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
              <ContentPresenter />
            </Border>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </ToggleButton.Style>

  ...
</ToggleButton>
```

Comment: So it was the toggle button style?, this worked for me perfectly, thanks

Comment: @Draxalot2 No, the `Template` of the `ToggleButton` is the reason. The default template defines triggers or visual states to handle appearance based on state changes like mouse over. The style is only used to override the default template.

Comment: The selected content of the ComboBox always appears at the left most position. I've tried altering the Padding and Margin, what's the problem?

Comment: @Draxalot2 In your `ComboBox` style you have a `ContentPresenter` called _ContentSite_. Modify its `Margin` to manipulate the selected item's position.

Comment: @Draxalot2 In case the `ComboBox` has editing enabled, then the margins or paddings of `PART_EditableTextBox` have precedence over the settings of `ContentPresenter`.